# How can I create a new column in a pandas pivot table with only matching values of populated columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas pivot table that lists individuals in rows and data sources across the columns. There are hundreds of individuals going down amongst the rows and hundreds of sources going across along the columns.

```
      Desired_Value  Source_1  Source_2  Source_3 ... Source_50
person1     20          20         20                    20
person2      5           5                    5           5
person3   Review         3          4         4           4
...
person50     1           1                                1
```

What I want to do is create the Desired_Value column above. I want to pull in a value so long as it matches across all values (ignoring blank fields). If values do not match I want to show Review.

I use this pandas command to print my df to excel currently (without any Desired_Value column):

```
df13 = df12.pivot_table(index='person', columns = 'source_name', values = 'actual_data', aggfunc='first')
```

I'm new to Python so apologies if this is a silly question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one method to do it:

```
df = df13.copy()
df = df.astype('Int64') # So NaN and Int values can coexist

# Create new column at the front of the data frame
df['Desired_Value'] = np.nan
cols = df.columns.tolist()
cols = cols[-1:] + cols[:-1]
df = df[cols]

# Loop over all rows and flag columns for review
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    val = row.dropna().unique()
    if len(val) == 1:
        df.loc[idx, 'Desired_Value'] = val
    else:
        df.loc[idx, 'Desired_Value'] = 'Review'

print(df)
```

```
         Desired_Value  Source_1  Source_2  Source_3  Source_50
person1             20        20        20       NaN         20
person2              5         5       NaN         5          5
person3         Review         3         4         4          4
person50             1         1       NaN       NaN          1
```

Comment: You're welcome! Feel free to accept this answer if it was helpful.